# Continuous Error Triggering in Next.js Dashboard Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with a Next.js dashboard component that's causing an error to be continuously triggered. The component is supposed to check for user permission and render accordingly. However, when I change the code from return <>no permission</> to throw new Error('error'), the error is triggered repeatedly. I've included the relevant code snippets below:

**Dashboard Component:**

```
"use client"
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Dashboard({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(false);
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const permission = !!session && (session.user as any).uid === params.id;

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      setHasPermission(permission);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  }, [params.id, session, permission]);

  if (!hasPermission) {
    throw new Error('No permission'); // Throw error if permission is not granted
  }

  return <p>Permission granted. You can proceed.</p>;
}
```

**Error Component:**

```
"use client"
export default function Error({
  error,
  reset,
}: {
  error: Error
  reset: () => void
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{error.message}</h2>
      <button onClick={() => reset()}>Try again</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Despite my best efforts, the error seems to be triggering repeatedly. Could anyone please help me identify the cause of this continuous error triggering and suggest how to resolve it? I'm open to any insights, debugging tips, or best practices.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: A React component is designed to return a value, not deliberately throw an error. Why you are doing so?